# Few of the URLs working by placing (.) dot in the end of URL in Sitecore based website

Tags: presentation

A few of our website URLs are displaying blank pages. However when we append `.` at the end of the URL, it renders the page correctly. We're not sure how/why a majority of pages are working fine but a few pages are only working by putting `.` at the end of the URL.

For example

- `www.testsite.com/about-us` shows a blank page
- `www.testsitec.com/about-us.` works fine

Has anyone experienced such issue with Sitecore website?

## Important Info

- Windows 2016 Server
- Sitecore 8.1 Update-3

Regards,
Sumit Bajaj

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! Can you identify any commonalities among the pages that exhibit this behavior? Have you tried replicating it on the same server with a fresh install of the same version of Sitecore?

Comment: Do you have any custom modules that might be interferring with the default OOTB Sitecore behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Yes we have custom modules but I am assuming, if custom module is culprit - it should impact all pages. However, there are only few pages which are impacted. 

Few of the pages with same template working and few are taking us to No-Page found. Same pages works when you put a dot(.) at the last of the URL which is making the issue wired.

Comment: Have you checked the item name and display name to see if a period is there?

Comment: Yes, there is no dot(.) in item or display name. We tested the same solution on Windows 2012 and everything is working. Looks something related to Windows 2016 OS.